# Interop GetActiveObject("Word.Application") not recognizing open Word doc?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have some C# code that I want to apply to a single open Word document using Interop. Below's my attempt.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = 
    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application) 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

if( application != null && application.Documents.Count > 0)
{
    Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
}
```

`application` is non-null but `application.Documents.Count` is equal to zero even though I have a Word document open? If I remove the test for `application.Documents.Count > 0` and then this line

```
Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
```

throws the error

> System.Runtime.InteropServics.COMException: 'This command is not
>   available because no document is open.'

Is there something additional I need to do for application to recognize my open Word doc?

Comment: Your problem may be related to this article [GetObject or GetActiveObject cannot find a running Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238610/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application), so please refer to it.

Comment: Is the Word application open with an open Word document in view?

Comment: @kunif my Word doc has been in and out of focus many times so unfortunately that article doesn't apply

Comment: @trix Yes, the Word doc is in view

Comment: Working now. I came across a thread that said updating VS fixed the problem. I was fairly up to date, but tried regardless (15.7.3 -> 15.7.6), which required a system reboot. Either the reboot or the update fixed the issue.

Comment: It might have been the reboot. If this happens again, open the Task Manager and see how many winword.exe processes are running. Only one such process will be accessible to GetActiveObject - usually the first Word instance started in a Windows session. If that has been left "orphaned", then your code won't be able to pick it up.